# How to force Scroller scrollbars to overlap content in Flex 4.0

Tags: apache-flex, scroller

I have the following spark Scroller

```
<s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" gap="0">
    <s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:DataGroup width="100%" height="100%" itemRenderer="components.grid.GridItemRenderer">
            <s:layout>
                <s:VerticalLayout gap="0" />
            </s:layout>
        </s:DataGroup>
    </s:Scroller>
</s:VGroup>
```

which is set to 100% width. The DataGroup is also set to 100% width. What I want to achieve is for the scroller's vertical scrollbar to OVERLAP the DataGrid. In other words I want the DataGroup to maintain the width of the outer VGroup even when the vertical scrollbar is displayed. I don't need the vertical scrollbar to move my content to the left, i want it to be displayed in top of that. Anybody has any idea?

Hope to have made myself clear enough, thanks to everyone!

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but have you tried using constraints?

Comment: Sorry but I'm mot sure how to be more specific than that! I want the scrollbars to be displayed ON TOP of the scrolling content, not resize it. I don't mind the scrollbars to hide some of my content. I just don't want the content to be resized when the scrollbars appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after much struggling I ended up changing my mxml markup so I could achieve what I was looking for. Instead of trying to overlap the scroller's scrollbar over the scroller's content, I droped the scroller completely and wraped my content within a group. Added a s:VScrollBar with a viewport pointing to the forementioned group and positioned this scrollbar over the group's content.

Comment: Thank you for your question and your answer. It helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Does setting Scroller.measuredSizeIncludesScrollBars to true achieve what you are looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I gave up trying to solve it this way so I changed my markup. See my answer below.